# A RenderFlex overflowed by 224 pixels on the bottom

Tags: flutter

How to fix the following error?

> A RenderFlex overflowed by 224 pixels on the bottom.

on the Column widget

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Read message'),
      ),
      body: Column( //the error is here
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0).copyWith(bottom: 10),
            child: Row( ...
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap your `Column` with a `SingleChildScrollView`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the device screen, these widgets can overflow, there are few solutions to handle it.

1. Use Column wrapped in SingleChildScrollView

SingleChildScrollView(
child: Column(children: children),
)

2. Use ListView

ListView(
children: children
)

3. Use combination of both Column and ListView(you should use Expanded/Flexible, or give a fixed height to the ListView when doing so).

Column(
children: [
...children.take(2).toList(), // show first 2 children in Column
Expanded(
child: ListView(
children: children.getRange(3, children.length).toList(),
), // And rest of them in ListView
),
],
)